# WebDriverArgumentException on attempt to click a Submit button

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm writing a unit test to upload CSV file in Jira.
I initialize the submit button By.Id() as shown on the screenshot below

[image]

I use the `wait.Until()` method to make sure that the element is present.

When I run the test, I receive `openQA.Selenium.WebDriverArgumentException 'invalid argument'` Not much description is provided by Selenium of what is causing the exception.

[image]

So dear QAs, have you ever bumped into this issue?

Comment: you're not using a proper webdriverwait on that link... so if it does return an exception or a null, that's what your "var" will be.  (you should probably try/catch the call so you can understand more and type it to webelement...)  I think in C# that's "IWebElement browseButton = ..."?